# Problems with using \tikzmath to draw ellipses

Tags: tikzmath

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\usepackage{onimage}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{txfonts,graphics,url}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{bm} 
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzmath{ \r = 6; }; 
        \draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (\r and \r/2 );
        \draw [thick,domain=180:360] plot ({\r*cos(\x)}, {\r*sin(\x)});
        \fill[black] (0, 0) circle (\r/6);
        \draw[red,line width=0.4pt] (\r/6/1.4,\r/6/1.4)--(\r/2, \r/2);
        \draw[red,line width=0.4pt] (-\r/2, 0)--(-\r/2-\r/4, \r/4);
        \draw[red,line width=0.4pt] (0,-\r/2)--(3*\r/4, -\r);
        \draw[red] (\r/2/sqrt(2), \r/2/sqrt(2))coordinate (A)node[right] {A};
        \draw[red] (-\r/2-\r/4, \r/4)coordinate (A)node[left,align=left] {B};
        \draw[red] (3*\r/4, -\r)coordinate (A)node[right,align=left] {C};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Compilation prompts that there are errors in `\draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (\r and \r/2 );` and `\draw[red] (\r/2/sqrt(2), \r/2/sqrt(2))coordinate (A)node[right] {A};` in the above code.
If I change them into `\draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (2 and 1 );` and `\draw[red] (\r/2/1.4, \r/2/1.4)coordinate (A)node[right] {A};`, there will be no problem.

But how can I make the initial code with parameters work correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Some explanations of [@ljguo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651642):

In `\draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (\r and \r/2);`, the space between command `\r` and `and` is skipped by TeX, but the syntax of `ellipse` requires explicit spaces before and after `and`.

Thus you need some tricks to reserve the space between `\r` and `and`, of which one is to wrap `\r` in braces (Wrapping `\r/2` is not necessary):

```tex
\draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse ({\r} and \r/2);
```

In `\draw[red] (\r/2/sqrt(2),\r/2/sqrt(2))coordinate ...;`, the culprit is the wrongly-paired parentheses `(` and `)`. Unfortunately, tikz doesn't take nested parentheses into account, thus what tikz sees is a coordinate `( \r/2/sqrt(2  )`. Bracing trick applies for this case as well:

```tex
\draw[red] ({\r/2/sqrt(2)},{\r/2/sqrt(2)})coordinate ...;
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It was great.

Answer (score 1):

```tex
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzmath{\r = 6; } 
        \draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse ({\r} and {\r/2}); %edit
        \draw [thick,domain=180:360] plot ({\r*cos(\x)}, {\r*sin(\x)});
        \fill[black] (0, 0) circle (\r/6);
        \draw[red,line width=0.4pt] (\r/6/1.4,\r/6/1.4)--(\r/2, \r/2);
        \draw[red,line width=0.4pt] (-\r/2, 0)--(-\r/2-\r/4, \r/4);
        \draw[red,line width=0.4pt] (0,-\r/2)--(3*\r/4, -\r);
        \draw[red] ({\r/2/sqrt(2)},{\r/2/sqrt(2)})coordinate (A)node[right] {A}; %edit
        \draw[red] (-\r/2-\r/4, \r/4)coordinate (A)node[left,align=left] {B};
        \draw[red] (3*\r/4, -\r)coordinate (A)node[right,align=left] {C};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's useful. 